# Adding Application Security for Cakeshop (Quorum) on Azure?

Tags: quorum, microsoft-azure, cakeshop

Is there a way to set a password to the `cakeshop` UI when using Azure for Quorum deployment? In order to prevent Ethereum accounts being generated or smart contracts being deployed via the publicly accessible websites!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to change the network security settings, so that Cakeshop and the administrative website can't be accessed at all.

Go to:  `Dashboard` --> `Resource groups` --> `Your group` --> `Name @ Network security group`

Change the following inbound security rules from `Allow` to `Deny`:

1. `allow-cakeshop`
2. `allow-etheradmin`